# Quick Books Integration error

Tags: quickbooks

We have been using Quick Books integration with a program called Mietrak for a long time now and posting invoices to QB from mietrak always worked just fine until the other day when this error popped up Export Invoice 'xxxxx' Error
Details: Details:
Error Message: There is an invalid reference to QuickBooks Item "xxxx" in the Invoice line.
QuickBooks error message: Invalid argument. The specified record does not exist in the list
Occurred by: Export Invoice
I did repair the QBFC. And reinstalled it 
Does anyone know the Source of this error and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the item referred to in the request exist in QuickBooks? What type of item is it?

Usually this specific error message indicates that the item being referred to by the integration application doesn't exist, or is not active. Check to make sure it exists and is active. If it doesn't exist/is inactive, create it as an active item in QuickBooks.